# How do I pass values from views to controller

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

In a view, When we route a button to a function inside the controller, how can we pass two or more values from present during that view.

I was practicing creating a result management system of students. In the view routed from index of ResultController, we have link options to view mark sheet of class ..or individual student. When we click on select class, it redirects to a view where there is two dropdowns to choose the class and batch of students. When we choose respected class and batch, the values class_id and batch_id is routed to function result inside ResultControler, we select students from that class and batch.. and respected subjects and return a view. In that view, we show the marksheet of students(if theres one), and below I have included a button to add marks/create marksheet.

But, I am so confused how I can pass those class_id and batch_id to create function inside ResultController, from the button.

```
public function index()
{
    return view('resultmainpage');
}



public function choose()
{
    $classes= Sclass::all();
    $batches= Batch::all();

    return view('chooseclassbatchresult',compact('classes','batches'));
}

public function result(Request $request)
{
    $classid = $request->class;
    $batchid = $request->batch; 
    //dd($batchid);

    $students =Student::where('sclass_id',$classid)
                        ->where('batch_id', $batchid)
                        ->whereHas('subject')
                        ->get();

    $class= Sclass::findOrFail($classid);                    

    return view('showstudentresult',compact('students','class','classid','batchid'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
     // I need class_id and batch_id here


   // dd($classidd);

    $students = Student::where('sclass_id',$classid)
                        ->where('batch_id',$batchid)
                        ->whereDoesntHave('subject')
                        ->get();

         //dd($students);
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/rms','MainPageController@index')->name('rms');

Route::get('results/choose','ResultController@choose')->name('chooseresult');

Route::post('/showstudentresult','ResultController@result')->name('showstudentresult');

Route::resource('results','ResultController');
```

chooseclassbatchresult.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')
    <h1>Please Choose the Class and Respected Batch Of Student For Result</h1>

    </br>
    </br>

    <form action="{{route('showstudentresult')}}" method="post">
        @csrf

        <p>
            <label>Class Name</label>

            <select name='class'>
                @foreach($classes as $class)
                    <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            </br>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Batch</label>
            <select name='batch'>

                @foreach($batches as $batch)
                    <option value="{{$batch->id}}">{{$batch->batch}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

        </p>

        </br>

        <input type="submit" value="View">
    </form>

    </br>
    </br>
    </br>

    <h1>OR</h1>

    <h3>
        <button><a href={{route('students.create')}}>Add New Student</a></button>
    </h3>
@endsection
```

Showstudentresult.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')

    <table border=1>
        <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>S.N</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Roll NO</th>
            @foreach($class->subjects as $subject)
                <th>{{$subject->name}}</th>
            @endforeach
            <th>Total Mark</th>
            <th>Percentage</th>
            <th>Division</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $id = 1; ?>

        @foreach($students as $student)
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id;?></td>
                <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->roll}}</td>
                @foreach($student->subjects as $subject)
                    <th>{{$subject->pivot->mark}}</th>
                @endforeach
                <td>{{$student->result->total_mark}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->result->percentage}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->result->division}}</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button><a href="{{route('students.edit',$student->id)}}">Edit</a></button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="{{route('students.destroy',$student->id)}}" method="post">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('DELETE')
                                    <input type="submit" value="Delete"
                                           onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the student?')">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php $id++ ?>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </br>
    </br>

    <button><a href={{results.create}}>Create New</a></button>
@endsection
```

Comment: Please can you add your blade file.

Comment: Please have a look.

Comment: I would suggest creating a separate page similar to `chooseclassbatchresult` with a form that submits the data to create.

Answer (score 0):

As Ross Wilson suggested in comment

> I would suggest creating a separate page similar to
>   chooseclassbatchresult with a form that submits the data to create

Add a route in your routes files like:

```
Route::post('/createPage', 'ResultController@createPage')->name('createPage');
```

In **ResultController** add the following function:

```
public function createPage(Request $request)
{
    // Get your required ids here
    $classid = $request->class;
    $batchid = $request->batch; 
    //dd($classid);
    //dd($batchid );
}
```

In your `chooseclassbatchresult` view add another form like below

```
<form action="{{ route('createPage') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <p>
            <label>Class Name</label>

            <select name='class'>
                @foreach($classes as $class)
                    <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            </br>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Batch</label>
            <select name='batch'>

                @foreach($batches as $batch)
                    <option value="{{$batch->id}}">{{$batch->batch}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

        </p>

        </br>

        <input type="submit" value="View">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. I got a way around my question. I learned that you can use input type="hidden" to carry those values back to the controller.

Create a route:

```
Route::post('/create_res', 'ResultController@create_res')->name('results.create_res');
```

In the View, `chooseclassbatchresult.blade.php`

```
<form action="{{route('results.create_res')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf

<input type="hidden" name="classid" value="{{$classid}}">
<input type="hidden" name="batchid" value="{{$batchid}}"> 


<input type="submit" value="Create Mark Sheet">

</form>
```

In the Result Controller;

```
public function create_res(Request $request){


        $classid = $request->classid;

        $batchid = $request->batchid;



        $students = Student::where('sclass_id',$classid)
                            ->where('batch_id',$batchid)
                            ->whereDoesntHave('subject')
                            ->get();

         $classes= Sclass::findOrFail($classid);   
         //dd($students);            


        return view('addmarksheet',compact('students','classes'));
    }
```